# How to get highest matching records first of select query mysql

Tags: mysql, search, select-query

Please do not down rate my question, because i'm new to MySQL. My Question is;

I have a table named `'item'`, and it has `'id'`, `'timestamp'`, `'title'` columns.
consider the table has following records in above order(id, timestamp, title).

```
100, 2016-01-12 12:26:30, sony bravia 32" Lcd TV

103, 2016-01-12 12:27:30, PSP 2 sony brand new

108, 2016-01-12 12:28:30, Xperia Aqua M2 brand new Sony mobile phone
```

Help me to create an SQL query to search `'title'` column that shows results as highest matching records first.

> As example, if we search `"new Sony xperia phone"` it should return
>   results as following order.

```
108, 2016-01-12 12:28:30, Xperia Aqua M2 brand new Sony mobile phone

103, 2016-01-12 12:27:30, PSP 2 sony brand new

100, 2016-01-12 12:26:30, sony bravia 32" Lcd TV
```

> Because highest matching record should come first.

108, 2016-01-12 12:28:30, `Xperia` Aqua M2 brand `new` `Sony` mobile `phone`

103, 2016-01-12 12:27:30, PSP 2 `sony` brand `new`

100, 2016-01-12 12:26:30, `sony` bravia 32" Lcd TV

Comment: Maybe see MATCH AGAINST with a fulltext index - but beware of its limitations too

Comment: I think you've misunderstood what Stack Overflow is for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the answer. First make your appropriate columns 'Full Text' index. Then use the following query.

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE MATCH(`column_name`) AGAINST('your searching keywords');
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try a query like that

```
SELECT 
    *, 
    if((CHAR_LENGTH(title) - CHAR_LENGTH(replace(lower(title), 'new','')))>0,1,0) +
    if((CHAR_LENGTH(title) - CHAR_LENGTH(replace(lower(title), 'sony','')))>0,1,0) +
    if((CHAR_LENGTH(title) - CHAR_LENGTH(replace(lower(title), 'xperia','')))>0,1,0) +
    if((CHAR_LENGTH(title) - CHAR_LENGTH(replace(lower(title), 'phone','')))>0,1,0) as matches
FROM item
ORDER BY matches DESC
```

the item with highest number of matches will be on top of the list

[SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2696c8/8)